# How to call prototype function within prototype function onclick event

Tags: javascript

How can I call prototype function within inside another prototype function `onclick` event in JavaScript?

```
function foo(){
    this.table = '';
}

foo.prototype.abc = function(){
    this.table = document.getElementById("tableID");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                this.xyz(this);
            };
        }
    }
}

foo.prototype.xyz = function(tableCell){
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
}
```

If I just call this `tableText` function instead of `this.xyz` it will work fine, but using `this.xyz` gives error in console `this.xyz(this)` is not a function

```
function tableText(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell.innerHTML);
}
```

My browser showing error but not JSFiddle
[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v4kpcc5h/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block of code:

```
table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
    this.xyz(this);
};
```

`this` represents the `td` HTML object, not `foo`. You have to keep a reference of `foo` and pass it into `onclick` function, like this:

```
foo.prototype.abc = function(){
    var that = this; //Keep a reference of `foo`
    this.table = document.getElementById("tableID");
    if (table != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
            table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
                //this.xyz(this);
                // "that" refer to the function foo
                // "this" refer to the current table cell (td)
                that.xyz(this);
            };
        }
    }
}
```